# Linking to \phantomsection with \ref does not work in make4ht

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Top of document

\section{Section heading}
Top of section

. \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\
. \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\

\phantomsection
\label{fooref}
We want to create a reference to this part of the document.

. \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\
. \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ . \\

Go to reference \ref{fooref}.

Bottom of document.
\end{document}
```

If I build my document with `pdflatex foo.tex && pdflatex foo.tex` and open `foo.pdf` with a PDF viewer, clicking on the reference created by `\ref{fooref}` takes me to the `\phantomsection` where `\label{fooref}` is present.

But if I build my document with `make4ht foo.tex` and open `foo.html` with a browser, clicking on the reference created by `\ref{fooref}` takes me to the top of the page. Is this a bug? Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: @JohnKormylo there is no reason why make4ht shouldn't be able to use anchor, it is not different to other anchors. But make4ht seems to ignore the destination name in the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\makeatletter
\def\phantomsection{%
 \Hy@GlobalStepCount\Hy@linkcounter
 \xdef\@currentHref{likesection.\the\Hy@linkcounter}%
 \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{\@currentHref}\hyper@anchorend}%
 \edef\@currentlabel{\the\Hy@linkcounter}%
 \AnchorLabel%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It redefines the default definition of `\phantomesection` used by TeX4ht,  it adds the `\label` support thanks to these lines:

```
\edef\@currentlabel{\the\Hy@linkcounter}%
\AnchorLabel%
```

The first line defines value of the reference that will be used in text, the second inserts the link destination into the text.

This is the resulting HTML code:

```html
<!-- l. 5 --><p class='noindent'>Top of document
</p>
   <h3 class='sectionHead' id='section-heading'><span class='titlemark'>1   </span> <a id='x1-10001'></a>Section heading</h3>
<!-- l. 8 --><p class='noindent'>Top of section
</p><!-- l. 10 --><p class='indent'>   . <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />
</p><!-- l. 13 --><p class='indent'>   <a id='likesection.1'></a> <a id='x1-1001x1'></a> We want to create a reference to this part of the document.
</p><!-- l. 17 --><p class='indent'>   . <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />. <br class='newline' />
</p><!-- l. 24 --><p class='indent'>   Go to reference <a href='#x1-1001x1'>1<!-- tex4ht:ref: fooref  --></a>.
</p><!-- l. 26 --><p class='indent'>   Bottom of document. </p>
```

As you can see, `<a id='x1-1001x1'></a>` is inserted in the place of `\phantomsection`, and `<a href='#x1-1001x1'>1</a>` points to that.